# How can I use an Alternate DB connection in Kohana 3.1

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-db

If a run the following bit of code from a Kohana 3.1 controller

```
$query = DB::select("select * from foo");
$results = $query->execute();
foreach($results as $result)
{
    var_dump($result);
}
```

Kohana will attempt to connect to the database using information from the array returned by `application/config/database.php`.  Specifically, if will use the information set in the **default** group.

```
return array
(
    'default' => array
    (
        'type'       => 'mysql',
        'connection' => array(
            /**
             * The following options are available for MySQL:
             *
             * string   hostname     server hostname, or socket
             * string   database     database name
             * string   username     database username
             * string   password     database password
             * boolean  persistent   use persistent connections?
             *
             * Ports and sockets may be appended to the hostname.
             */
            'hostname'   => 'localhost',
            'database'   => 'kohana',
            'username'   => FALSE,
            'password'   => FALSE,
            'persistent' => FALSE,
```

However, this configuration array accepts multiple top level items (called db-groups, I think). How can/should I tell Kohona 3.1 to make a connection and query using information that's set in a **non-default** db-group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a database group as an argument of `execute`

Check out the source code: [Line 201 of classes/kohana/database/query.php](https://github.com/kohana/database/blob/3.1%2Fmaster/classes/kohana/database/query.php#L201) and [Database::instance()](https://github.com/kohana/database/blob/3.1%2Fmaster/classes/kohana/database.php#L37)

```
$this->execute('group');
```

You could also write a query starting with `$query = Database::instance('group')`